# HTML E-Mail formatting issues in Apple Mail Client

Tags: html, email, html-email, newsletter, email-client

I'm trying to create a HTML-based newsletter. In Apple's mail client I noticed that my telephone numbers, zip codes, and addresses were all automatically turned into links, which is not what I intended.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, or will I have to resort to work-arounds such as using images in place of the text? Perhaps if I choose a certain `<!DOCTYPE>` this will change the formatting given by the client?

Comment: Hi. I've tried to completely rewrite your question for clarity. In doing so, I've possibly mis-interpreted some statements. Please tell me / revert the changes if this is not the case. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you also provide some code from your email so that we can try and work out the exact problem.

Comment: Apart from what @IanClark mentioned, this site is dedicated to programming.  You can try asking the same at http://superuser.com

Comment: Thank you for your correction it is clear as possible ;) I though that this forum concerned html coding.

Comment: ...but what is the best way to post DOM code there ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's just how Mail handles e-mails, like it's a feature built into the app, rather than a bug in the HTML

Comment: Okay I understand. I'm sure your opinion is true. Thank you all I can save time now

Comment: Yes, this site is related to coding. But from your question I've got impression that it's your Mail Client behavior... Have you tried looking at that mail in another mail client?

Comment: Of course, but Mail is the only one that made this "mistake". But think Electric Coffee's answer is true. That's just the software not problem of code. Thanx

Comment: Presumably named, Apple highlights everything that seems to be information that should make it accessible. In other words, as soon as he reads a sequence of numbers or an address, he highlighted. This can cause problems when we have requirements in terms of visual rendering or if some informations are useless.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs The [html-email] tag is for coding, same as you need to fix bugs in IE8 you need to deal with the quirks of Outlook's MSO rendering engine. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Apple clients (and GMail too) comb through text and add an `<a>` tag around what it sees as an address or phone number. Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .applelinksBlack a {color:#000000 !important; text-decoration:none;}
</style>

Visit our studio at <span class="applelinksBlack" style="color:#000000 !important">3 Abbey Rd, London NW8 9AY, United Kingdom, or call 1-555-555-5555</span>
```

Comment: By the way, in Apple Mail you can get the source of any email by going to View > Message > Raw Source. Then find / delete all the "3D"s. (putting 3D in front of some attributes is just something Apple Mail does.)

Comment: Sorry I'm late ! Thank you for your answer. +1 I don't get how do you know this but it's an useful information and I've never inspected a htm-mail source from Apple's Mail agent... Thanx a lot !